# How to run iOS app in background on iOS 12

Tags: ios

I have an app that runs in the background without problem on iOS 8, 9, 10, and 11. However, it stops running in the background on iOS 12.1 (it's killed after 180 seconds).

I notice that some apps still work ok like Skype, Facebook, Viber, etc. 
and I notice that Apple released iOS 12.2 now.

Does anyone know how these apps can run in the background without any problems?

Comment: As Nicolas correctly point out, only specific app types are allowed to respond to callbacks events in the background. You can find all information you need in the Apple Documentation https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

Answer (score 2):

If your app is killed after 180 seconds, it is because your app ask the system to continue running for a while when your app goes to background.

This request is done using `[UIApplication beginBackgroundTaskWithName]`: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1623051-beginbackgroundtaskwithname?language=objc

As stated in the documentation,

> This method requests additional background execution time for your app.

This additional time was 180 seconds (I think it's closer to 30 seconds since iOS 12).

If you need yourapplication to be really running in background, you have to declare a `background mode` in your application's capabilities in Xcode:

[image]

That's the way the applications you listed works in background (essentially `Voice over IP` mode).

Comment: dear, thanks for your reply. However, i've already declare the my app to run in background in capibility . and my app work without any trouble on ios 8.9,10,11. However, it begin to be kill in ios 12.1 . Do you have any other idea about problem?